# Should ResultSet be kept open in a batch processing to avoid multiple fetch queries

Tags: java, sql, mariadb, resultset

I am fetching records (of large data set, around 1 Million records)from MariaDB in batches of size 500 (by using 'limit'). 
For each fetch iteration I am opening and closing the connection.

In my peer review I was advised to fetch the result set once and  batch process by iterating on the result set itself, i.e. without closing the connection.

Is the second method right way of doing it ?

Edit : After I fetch records in batches of size 500 I am updating a field for each record and putting it on a messaging queue.

Comment: We need more information.  How many total records do you need to fetch?  What are you doing in between batches of 500 records?

Comment: why are you not using a DBCP?

Comment: @ScaryWombat :  Yes, we are, though this question is not about that.

Comment: *without closing the connection.* if you a re using DHCP then the connection is not really closed

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the second method is the right way to do it.  Here are some reasons:

- There is overhead to running the query multiple times.
- The underlying data might change in the tables you are using, and the separate batches might be inconsistent.
- You are depending on the ordering of the results and the sorting might have duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

```
Your program starts
    Connect to database
        do some SQL (selects/inserts/whatever)
        do some more SQL (selects/inserts/whatever)
        do some more SQL (selects/inserts/whatever)
        ...
    Disconnect from database
Your program ends
```

That is, keep the connection open as long as needed during the program.  (Even if you don't explicitly disconnect, the termination of your program will do the termination.  This is important to note when doing a web site -- each 'page' is essentially a separate 'program'; the db connection cannot be held between pages.)

You have another implied question...  "Should I grab a batch of rows at once, then process them in the client?"  The answer is "It depends".

- If the processing can be done in SQL, it is *probably* much more efficient to do it there.  Example:  summing up some numbers.
- If you fetch some rows from one table, then for each of those rows, fetch row(s) from another table...  It will be much more efficient to use an SQL `JOIN`.
- "Batching" may not be relevant.  The client interface is probably

  ```
  Fetch rows from a table (possibly all rows, even if millions)
  Look at each row in turn.
  ```

Please provide the specifics of what you will be doing with the million rows so we can discuss more specifically.

Polling loop:

If you check for new things to do only once a minute, do reconnect each time.

Given that, it does not make sense to hang onto a resultset between pools.

Comment: Pseudo code is as follows:
     scheduler starts 
            while(no more records) {
                       connects to database ;
                       fetch records;
                       close database connection;
                
               }

Comment: @vkg - I added more.

Answer (score -1):

Opening and closing a database connection is quite time consuming. Keeping the connection open will save a lot of time.

Comment: In general, database connections should be closed as soon as the application is done using them.  The issue here is what "done" is.